# Custom view for data input (in-app (non-system) keyboard)

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a custom keyboard that gets loaded from an .xib file.

I decided to go with an in-app only keyboard rather than a system-wide keyboard because the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) states:

> Make sure a custom, systemwide keyboard is indeed what you want to
>   develop. To provide a fully custom keyboard for just your app or to
>   supplement the system keyboard with custom keys in just your app, the
>   iOS SDK provides other, better options. Read about custom input views
>   and input accessory views in [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) in Text
>   Programming Guide for iOS.

**Implementation highlights**

- Keyboard layout comes from Keyboard.xib, whose file owner is Keyboard.swift.
- Keyboard.xib uses auto layout to resize all individual keys (`UIButton`s) when the keyboard view size changes.
- Use of a delegate to communicate between the keyboard view and the view controller.
- Use of the `inputView` method of `UITextField` to replace the system keyboard with my custom keyboard.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initialize custom keyboard
        let keyboardView = Keyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 300))
        keyboardView.delegate = self

        // replace system keyboard with custom keyboard
        textField.inputView = keyboardView
    }

    // required method for keyboard delegate protocol
    func keyWasTapped(character: String) {
        textField.insertText(character)
    }
}
```

**Keyboard.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardDelegate {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
}

class Keyboard: UIView {

    var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Keyboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }

    @IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
    }

}
```

**Concerns**

- I never could find a single tutorial or full example of implementing an in-app only custom keyboard that makes use of the `inputView` method. This seems to work, but since I don't have anything else to compare it to, I wanted to run it by other programmers first.
- I've gotten the impression from various reading that using .xib files to build a view is an outdated practice.